# Nested VLOOKUP functions

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I am trying to get a `VLOOKUP` where if a value of greater than $100 is found then the value presented is 0.

I then want the function to perform where it calculates the value from a table and then performs another `VLOOKUP` to determine an additional value to add. I also want an `IFERROR` statement to allow for errors to present as a blank.

So far I have

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(F43,'Delivery Calculator'!A6:B11,2,TRUE)>100,
         "$0.00",
         (VLOOKUP(F43,'Delivery Calculator'!A6:B11,2,TRUE) +
         VLOOKUP(B27,'Delivery Calculator'!A14:C17,2,False)))),
         "")
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this/a possible fix? I am getting an error about too few arguments and may have just spent too much time on this function. Extra eyes would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You've got your backets `( )` wrong. This is what your formula looks like, if we format to be a little more readable:

```
=IFERROR(
    IF(
        VLOOKUP(F43,'Delivery Calculator'!A6:B11,2,TRUE)>100,
        "$0.00",
        (
            VLOOKUP(F43,'Delivery Calculator'!A6:B11,2,TRUE)+
            VLOOKUP(B27,'Delivery Calculator'!A14:C17,2,False)
        )
    )
),"")
```

You're passing only one argument to `IFERROR`, the `,"")` at the end is outside the `IFERROR`... It should be:

```
=IFERROR(
    IF(
        VLOOKUP(F43,'Delivery Calculator'!A6:B11,2,TRUE)>100,
        "$0.00",
        VLOOKUP(F43,'Delivery Calculator'!A6:B11,2,TRUE)+
        VLOOKUP(B27,'Delivery Calculator'!A14:C17,2,False)
    )
,"")
```

Or, without the spaces:

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(F43,'Delivery Calculator'!A6:B11,2,TRUE)>100,"$0.00",VLOOKUP(F43,'Delivery Calculator'!A6:B11,2,TRUE)+VLOOKUP(B27,'Delivery Calculator'!A14:C17,2,False)),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add whitespace/line breaks to divide the formula into logical sections (by syntax), the you should easily see where your major error occurs.

```
=IFERROR(
    IF(
        VLOOKUP(F43,'Delivery Calculator'!A6:B11,2,TRUE)>100,
        "$0.00",
        (
            VLOOKUP(F43,'Delivery Calculator'!A6:B11,2,TRUE)
            +
            VLOOKUP(B27,'Delivery Calculator'!A14:C17,2,False)
        )
        )
    ),
    ""
)
```

Notice how you have two close parentheses at the same level? It is obvious that this is a mistake and one of them should be removed.

Therefore your formula becomes:

```
=IFERROR(
    IF(
        VLOOKUP(F43,'Delivery Calculator'!A6:B11,2,TRUE)>100,
        "$0.00",
        (
            VLOOKUP(F43,'Delivery Calculator'!A6:B11,2,TRUE)
            +
            VLOOKUP(B27,'Delivery Calculator'!A14:C17,2,False)
        )
    ),
    ""
)
```

As a side note, you should verify that those `TRUE` values in your `VLOOKUP` are actually meant to be `TRUE`. These are generally meant to be `FALSE`.